# How to fix hyphen for sed using hd -c

Tags: sed, hexdump

I have a file (c.txt) with the following output. This is only one item in a large file.

```
7,VE,Bank–Charges
```

I am trying to run:

```
sed -i 's/-/ - /g' c.txt
```

to get the desired output of:

```
7,VE,Bank – Charges
```

which does not work.
Please note that there are many other hyphen combinations, such as Vehicle–Maintenance etc.

I have run the following command to understand the problem:

```
cat c.txt | head -n2 | tail -n1 | hd -c

00000000  37 2c 56 45 2c 42 61 6e  6b e2 80 93 43 68 61 72  |7,VE,Bank...Char|
0000000   7   ,   V   E   ,   B   a   n   k 342 200 223   C   h   a   r
00000010  67 65 73 0a                                       |ges.|
0000010   g   e   s  \n                                                
0000014
```

From this it is clear that the hyphen actually consists of 3 characters (342 200 223). So my question is how could I write a sed command that fixes all hyphen instances in the file of which there are many? Or is sed even usable here or are there other more useful options?

Comment: Replace both `-` with `–` in your sed command?

Comment: How so? I only have ```-``` on my keyboard.

Comment: copy/paste the offending character(s) from your input file into your sed command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was able to figure it out thanks to Cyrus.

```
sed -i 's/\xe2\x80\x93/ - /g' c.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\o342\o200\o223/ - /g' c.txt
```

This replaces the octal string `342 200 223` with  `-` .